# Docker: " login attempt to https://hub.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found" in Fedora 25

Tags: docker, virtualbox, fedora

I have Docker CE installed in Fedora 25.

When I try to login into docker hub using below command I am getting error.

```
$ docker login --username xxx --password yyy https://hub.docker.com/
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to 
https://hub.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

$ docker --version
 Docker version 17.07.0-ce, build 8784753

$ docker-machine --version
 docker-machine version 0.12.2, build 9371605
```

Notice that the same command works fine in Ubuntu 16.04
Only difference I can think of is ubuntu have docker and fedora have docker-ce.

Not sure why I get this error only on Fedora. I get this this error when Fedora is installed on virtual box VM.

Answer (score 20):

You need not specify the registry when it is hub.docker.com.

```
docker login --username xxx --password yyy
```

Use above command without URL and it should work

Comment: I get the below error when I didn't specify the dockerhub URL. The error is    ----> Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password

Comment: Try on some other OS and see if the same username and password works

Comment: yes. It works on Ubuntu 16.04 but fails on Fedora 25.

Comment: sure. Will do that.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when setting up a **Jenkins** pipeline for a **Docker** application.

The issue was that I was in my Jenkinsfile **build** stage I was using https://hub.docker.com as the **registry** for Docker:

```
stage('Push image') {
  /* Finally, we'll push the image with two tags:
  * First, the incremental build number from Jenkins
  * Second, the 'latest' tag.
  * Pushing multiple tags is cheap, as all the layers are reused. */
  docker.withRegistry('https://hub.docker.com', 'Dockerhub') {
    app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
    app.push("latest")
  }
}
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I simply had to modify the docker **registry** from https://hub.docker.com to https://registry.hub.docker.com:

```
stage('Push image') {
  /* Finally, we'll push the image with two tags:
  * First, the incremental build number from Jenkins
  * Second, the 'latest' tag.
  * Pushing multiple tags is cheap, as all the layers are reused. */
  docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'Dockerhub') {
    app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
    app.push("latest")
  }
}
```

And then for my **Dockerhub** credentials in **Jenkins** Configuration:

```
username: my_username (not my email address)
password: my_password
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**.

Comment: This solution just stopped working for me.

But i found this doku: https://appfleet.com/blog/building-docker-images-to-docker-hub-using-jenkins-pipelines/

that basically tells one to use the empty string as docker-registry parameter.
Makes sense if you think about it..

Comment: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/": unauthorized: incorrect username or password

Answer (score 3):

Docker Hub is the default registry, so there's no need to specify the registry (i.e., just docker login --username .... is sufficient).

However, the reason you're getting this error, is because hub.docker.com is the domain of the Docker Hub website, not the registry backing Docker Hub; the registry is located at index.docker.io, (e.g. docker login index.docker.io).

In short, run command like below

PS D:> docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: 
Password: 
Login Succeeded
PS D:>

Answer (score 2):

as discussed in [Couldn't login to docker hub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34872)
*it's possible the registry only implements V1 (or has not been configured to use the V2 specification, in which case the daemon has to be configured to support legacy registries*

you can verify that with the "docker info" command :

```
docker info
...
Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
...
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

consequently, it fails...

```
docker login --username my_login --password my_password
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

Comment: MaxReglisse - I have the problem in Fedora  25 which is running in VM But not in Ubuntu 16.10 which is host. When I run the command `docker info` the result is same (`Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/`).  I'm not sure why it is working in Ubuntu but not in Fedora. Any suggestions?

Comment: MaxReglisse - Any suggestions on my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above command mentioned by Tarun or just abbreviated parameters into the command with `-u` for USername and `-p` for Password.

Here's basic screen-shot for docker login

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command:

```
docker login
```

Then enter your username and password

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, you need not specify the registry.
However, a point to note is that the CLI does not transform the username to lowercase as the docker hub page does. Simply do a:

```
docker login --username <username-in-all-lowercase> --password <xxxxxx>
```

and you should be good to go.
If this fails try removing or renaming your `~/.docker/config.json` CLI configuration file.